# Trading on Charles Schwab shortly before the market closing time: "Your request will be processed on a best efforts basis. "

Tags: united-states, trading, schwab

I placed an ordered to buy some ETF on https://www.schwab.com/ shortly before the market closed and I saw the warning:

> Please Note: The market closes in approximately 3 minutes. Your request will be processed on a "best efforts" basis. (DO293)

I'm not sure why Schwab gives me this warning. Won't the order be executed exactly the same way as if I had placed the order earlier in the day?

[image]

Comment: Presumably your order is 'day only'.  There are also various extended hours options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Trading volume is generally heavier right as markets open and right before they close, so they are just warning you that it may not be possible to fill your order before the markets close, and it will be filled when they open the next day at the earliest (or not at all if your order was only good for the trading day).

"Best efforts" is a legal term that essentially means that they'll make every reasonable effort to fill your order but can not guarantee that it will be filled that day. It's most likely a blanket warning that they add, and not indicative of that particular ETF or trading activity at that time.

Comment: yes - it is easy to imagine that for some reason the system takes 3 minutes to process the order (i have seen very slow orders on my broker sometimes) and then the market has closed so it can't be filled.

Answer (score -5):

> Won't the order be executed exactly the same way as if I had placed the order earlier in the day?

Reddit users [FormerBroker_Burner](https://www.reddit.com/user/FormerBroker_Burner) and [this_guy_fks](https://www.reddit.com/user/this_guy_fks) [mentioned](https://redd.it/16h1pwo) [that](https://redd.it/16h1p6a) there is a closing auction at the NYSE, which changes the execution of orders placed within the last minutes of the trading day:

- [Closing Cross](https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/productsservices/Trading/ClosingCrossfaq.pdf).
- https://www.nyse.com/article/nyse-closing-auction-insiders-guide

Comment: So assuming that their responses are the correct answer (which I think they are not) what does that have to do with the warning you get? How is that an answer to your question?

Comment: @DStanley that answers "Won't the order be executed exactly the same way as if I had placed the order earlier in the day?". If it's incorrect, please let me know, my only goal is learning.